# MongoDB performance, is my performance expected?

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB server that I've just setup can handle about 2,500 writes per second, is this an acceptable rate? If not what is? What are your systems running at? What steps would you take to improve this?

To add a bit of detail, my objects were small, actually only a single 5 character string, written one by one with a small ruby script.

---

So as for servers I'm using Amazon EC2, and just a small little ruby script like:

```
task :test => :environment do |t, args|
  start_time = Time.now

  1000000.times do
    Item.create({:name => "#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{Time.now.to_i}-#{rand}")}"})
  end

  puts Time.now - start_time
end
```

But even when running both database and app on my local machine I get similar performance.

Comment: Are you inserting documents one at a time? If your driver support batch Insert you can get some significant performance improvements.

Comment: Insufficient information...2500 writes/second is not much. How large are your documents? In addition: ask a more specific question here. SO is not for asking meta questions.

Comment: Sorry @RestRisiko, I didn't know where a suitable place would have been to post this, so I just went ahead and did it, I figure it may help people get an idea of what to expect from mongo in the future.

Comment: It is an acceptable rate if that suits your demand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 2500 writes/second is **nothing** - especially not with 5-byte strings.
Decent hardware reaches up to 50k to 100k writes/second for typical small documents.
If your system only reaches this performance then you are using either old hardware or having other issues.

2500*5 = 12.5KB / seconds...sorry but every database should be faster....provide additional information about your setup etc..or your data processing/code is so slow for whatever so it can not saturate the database.

As said: MongoDB out of the box on commodity hardware is fast.